# MVC Pattern & Database Design

Tags: php, model-view-controller, database-design, doctrine, normalization

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, not sure if it's my coding or I'm just missing something.

I'm trying to refactor our internal fax application with doctrine (1.2) and using MVC - when a fax is received, it goes into a list. Then, a user can pick things to do with it - currently forward, archive or shred.

When they pick one of those, it generates a workflow action for the fax which inserts an entry into the following table:

```
fax_id | from_status_id | to_status_id | completed | cancelled
```

Initially, status is null to denote 'unactioned'

status_id looks up a row in the fax_status table.

Currently, the code looks like this

```
Controller:

function action_shred($fax_id)
{

    $fax = Doctrine_Core::getTable('fax')->findOneById($fax_id);

    // error handling for checking it exists and belongs to the user

    $fax->shred();

}
```

and in the model

```
function shred()
{

    $wf = new FaxWorkFlow();
    $wf->fax_id = $this->id;
    $wf->from_status_id = $this->status_id;
    $wf->to_status_id = Doctrine_Core::getTable('fax_status')->findOneByStatus("Shredded")->id;
    $wf->completed = 0;
    $wf->cancelled = 0;
    $wf->save();
    $this->status_id = Doctrine_Core::getTable('fax_status')->findOneByStatus("Queued")->id;

}
```

I'm also finding problems with things like searching for queued faxes as I have to do the following:

```
$queued_id = Doctrine_Core::getTable('fax_status')->findOneByStatus("Queued")->id;
$queued_faxes = Doctrine_Core::getTable('fax')->findByStatusId($queued_id);
```

Is there any problems with this or is there a better way of doing it? I just think the code looks very ugly, and it seems very hackish to search for the lookup value within the fax model (should this be moved to the faxworkflow model maybe?)

It's very tempting to hard-code the status values in to the model, but if they change in the future, that would cause problems.

overall I'm just looking for an opinion on if what i've got so far is 'correct' or if I need to look at recoding before I go too far down this route

Comment: Can you be a little more precise about the problems you're trying to address? Yes, the code is ugly - I would factor out "fax" and "fax workflow" to separate classes and hide the database stuff from the outside.

Comment: I don't know _doctrine_ so maybe my question is silly but... why did you model your state table as "from_status_id/to_status_id" ? I worked on fairly complex state-transition systems in the past, and to me having "action"+"status" (e.g.: "Shred"/"Completed") feels more natural.

Comment: @p.marino the reason I modelled it that way is because an item can be queued multiple times, so it provides a history - eg it has gone from archived to forwarded to shredded. that's three records in the workflow table

Comment: So you mean that if I send the same fax to two distinct receivers I get two records in the from/to status table? and then both go to "shredded"? This looks very cumbersome to me -  I would create a log table where the various actions (and their outcomes) are recorded and keep the items in one state only.

Comment: @p.marino:  +1 for splitting out the data (with current state) and the auditing of the state transitions.  I would go one further and automate the auditing of state transitions with triggers, if possible.  There's nothing to keep anyone that has rights on the DB system from running an update query directly against the data and bypassing the auditing application code completely.

Answer (score 0):

I want to address two issues found in the comments.

First, it is usually better generally to model completed status, not transition from one state to another.  The exception is when you need to model graphs  with recursive queries detailing the paths that were taken, and one can transition from a single state to several other states at once.  Otherwise there is nothing to be gained by the `from_state_id` and `to_state_id` duplication.  it would be better to have a timestamp field for tracking when an event happened, the state completed, and the fax id.

The second point is Matthew Wood's point about automating auditing using triggers.  In my experience this tends to cause two things to happen both of which are very good.  The first is that the auditing is harder to bypass.  That's the point he is making.  The second however is that it makes it harder to bypass the security assumptions of your application to the extent that your audit triggers depend on them.  If you have such assumptions active, if you violate them in such a way that the trigger fails and throws an error, your writes will be aborted.